# Generating pdf in Turkish Language fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

In put and out put data are getting different on pdf file generated through fpdf.

```
input: uçak is Turkish word
Output: uÃ§ak is Turkish word
```

What I am doing:

1. Convert arial.tft to .z and define php from http://fpdf.fruit-lab.de/index.php?id=3
2. Map: cp1254 for Turkish language.
3. Download only .z and define php file.
4. Both are copied in the font folder in fpdf.

I am using following code:

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddFont('ArialMT','','ArialMT.php');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('ArialMT','',35);
$pdf->Write(10,'uçak is Turkish word');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

which results in the following output:

```
uÃ§ak is Turkish word
```

Where am I making mistake? Do I have to do any additional task?

Comment: `FPDF` does not support unicode characters. There is a fork of `FPDF` called [tFPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php) that does.

Comment: How did you "map to the correct codepage"? Your *input* is still mapped to UTF-8, which is made clear by the incorrect *output*: `0xC3 0xA7` in hex, "Ã§" as literal character codes.

Comment: Now working well with tFPDF. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I answered this in the comments section above, but for future reference:

By default, `FPDF` does not support unicode characters. There are two *popular* extensions available, which are:

- [tFPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php) - A fork of `FPDF` with unicode support.
- [uFPDF](http://acko.net/blog/ufpdf-unicode-utf-8-extension-for-fpdf/) - A minor patch for unicode support. Contains lots of [examples](http://mpdf1.com/examples/example_utf8.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for Turkish language...

```
<?php

require('tfpdf.php');
$pdf = new tFPDF();

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);

$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',14);
$pdf->Cell(130 ,5,'Uçak',0,0);

$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',12);
$pdf->Cell(130 ,5,'Fıstıkçı Şahap',0,0);

$pdf->Output("fatura.pdf","D");
?>
```